# Is it possible to have dropdown autocomplete select options in ZSH or Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Is it possible to have dropdown autocomplete select options in the terminal with ZSH or Bash as shown in the image below? Here the regions(i.e. `ap-northeast-1`, `ap-northeast-1` etc) are predefined

[image]

Comment: Did you create this screenshot on your own? It seems like an interesting idea. Unclear if it actually exists in Zsh or Bash or any basic terminal functionality.

Comment: That's a great idea to develop such "plugin" for bash. Such a plugin does not exist currently. The closest is for bash commands - thefuck, which fixes last command and gives some options then. Automatic list of possible options would go over bash-completion package and would have to be supported by each of runned programs internally.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 No, I didn't create this screenshot. I noticed this while running  `aws configure sso` command. I found it interesting and wanted to know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this exists for Zsh, in the form of my [Zsh Autocomplete plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete).

Comment: I don't think the zsh autocomplete supports what I have shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @Nameless Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I did. In my screenshot the regions(i.e. ap-northeast-1, ap-northeast-1 etc) are predefined

Comment: Ah, right, you don’t want completions on the command line, but inside your custom command. That’s definitely possible with Zsh, but I don’t have time now to prototype it. In the meantime, this question and answer should get you on the right path: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120649/call-vared-and-complete-files-from-a-different-directory

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented using https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit

```py
from prompt_toolkit import prompt
from prompt_toolkit.completion import WordCompleter

html_completer = WordCompleter(['<html>', '<body>', '<head>', '<title>'])
text = prompt('Enter HTML: ', completer=html_completer)
print('You said: %s' % text)
```

[image]

Ref: https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/pages/asking_for_input.html#autocompletion